# Jenkins pipline with terraforn - how to get outpt variable feed into follwing Ansible stage

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

Folks,
I am going with a Jenkins Pipeline to get a git clone and then run a terraform to get an AWS instance deployed which does give me some outputs I will need in my Ansible Stage, to use the right IP and the password. Export a value from terraform and create a Jenkis var which I can use in my Jenkinsfile for the Ansible playbook.

The Terraform output.tf will show me:

```
output "S3_bucket_name" {
  value       = aws_s3_bucket.ddve6.bucket
  description = "The value you do need for DDVE configuration on the bucket name!"
}
output "Instance_id" {
  value       = aws_instance.terraform_ddve.id
  description = "EC2 instance ID for default sysadmin password"
}
output "DDVE_public_IP" {
  value       = aws_instance.terraform_ddve.public_ip
  description = "Public IP of your DDVE"
}
output "DDVE_DNS_Name" {
  value       = aws_instance.terraform_ddve.public_dns
  description = "Public DNS name of your DDVE"
}
output "Anzahl_Metadisk" {
  value       = var.amount_of_metadisk
  description = "Amount of attached metadata disk"
}
```

How can I create a Jenkins variable I can use on my

ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "DD_IP=terraform.DDVE_public_IP DD_password=terraform.Instance_id"

I am looking for some examples of how to exchange the data from different stages and use them.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can do it.

1. By using terraform template, you can generate your expected YAML file and make use of the file while running ansible.
   [terraform templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) - will explain to you how the template works
   and for your scenario, it would be like this :

**main.tf** / **output.tf**

```
locals {
    someVariable = templatefile("${path.module}/template.tpl", {
        dd_ip = aws_instance.terraform_ddve.public_ip, 
        dd_password = aws_instance.terraform_ddve.id
    })
}

output "neededForAnsible" {
  value = local.someVariable
}
```

**template.tpl**

```
DD_IP = ${dd_ip}
DD_password = ${dd_password}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node {
  stage('terraform') {
    sh """
        terraform init
        terraform plan
        terraform apply --auto-approve
    """
    //write the template output in a file
    def fileContent = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "terraform output neededForAnsible")
    writeFile file: "${WORKSPACE}/vars.yaml", text: fileContent
  }
  stage('ansible') {
     sh """
       ansible-playbook release.yml -e @vars.yaml
     """
  }
}
```

2. setting the terraform output on a groovy variable:

```
def dd_ip
def dd_password
node {
  stage('terraform) {
     sh """
        terraform init
        terraform plan
        terraform apply --auto-approve
     """
     // inject terraform out to a groovy variable
     dd_ip = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "terraform output DDVE_public_IP").trim()
     dd_password = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "terraform output Instance_id").trim()
     
  }
  stage('ansible') {
     sh """
       ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "DD_IP=${dd_ip} DD_password=${dd_password}"
     """
  }

}
```

Comment: as Samit said, many ways to do this, I would write to json file and extract any value using `jq` or write to yaml file and use `yq`. This json, or yaml file will be in the artifacts in Jenkins